# multi filter with URL values

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, filter, multiple-values

I know that I can filter a single field with a single value using parameter passing to a view or a page.
Something like:

> URL?FilterField1=ColumnName&FilterValue1=ValueToFilterOn

My question is can I filter multiple values from a single field
Something like:

> URL?FilterField1=ColumnName&FilterValue1=Value1ToFilterOn&FilterValue2=Value2ToFilterOn

This does not to seem to work. Will using javascript help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FilterValue2 is to be used togetter with FilterField2 to further limit the selection so you can specify

> URL?FilterField1=Column1&FilterValue1=Value1&FilterField2=Column2&FilterValue2=Value2

To select items where `Column1=Value1 AND Column2=Value2` but you can't specify multiple values for the same column

Answer (score 3):

URL?FilterName=Column1&FilterMultiValue=Value1;Value2

This should work. Only issue is that I'm not sure on how to do it for lookup column (SP online, it might be cause).